# how to invoke an action when control/shift is double clicked

Tags: c#

I'm using a form which a GUI is popped when the user clicks on CTRL+F7, for example.
How do I do the same thing when the user double clicks CONTROL or SHIFT?
With CTRL+F7, the user holds CTRL *while* clicking F7, this is different. I think measuring the time between the clicks is not what I need (so it is not 2 different keystrokes, but one), so how do I do that?
Thx.

Comment: how to clicking F7 or shift? :)

Comment: You will receive two keystrokes in your events, so measuring the time between the two should work

Answer (score 1):

```
    DateTime LastPressed = DateTime.Now;

    private MyControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
         if(e.Shift){
              if((DateTime.Now-LastPressed).TotalMilliSeconds< 400){ 
//if gap between two clicks are less than 400 milli seconds
                  //Double clicked
               }
               LastPressed = DateTime.Now;
         {
    }
```

Comment: This code will not work properly, the condition will accept events like SHIFT+OTHER KEY. It should be `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey)`

Comment: Thanks all. I'll check it in a few hours and post marked answer.